# How to reload the data of a table with vue and axios?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, vue.js, html-table, axios

Well, i have a table populated with `v-for: "usuario in usuarios"`. The initial charge does it correctly. But when i push the button "Buscar" only my `<p>{{nombre}}</p>` shows data. Look at these pictures:

[Table populated with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR39O.jpg)

In the above picture, the table was populated with data, through getUsuarios() method. But in the next picture the table only shows blank data.

[Table with blank data and `<p>{{nombre}}</p>`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htVyX.jpg)

Here are my codes:

**Template:**

```
        <div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h1><strong>Lista de nombres</strong></h1></div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="usuario in usuarios">
                                <td>{{usuario.Nombre}}</td>
                                <td>{{usuario.Apellido_P}}</td>
                                <td>{{usuario.Apellido_M}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <p>Buscar usuario</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="busqueda" placeholder="Buscar usuario" />
                    <button class="btn btn-default" v-on:click="buscarUsuario">Buscar</button>
                </div>
                <p>{{nombre}}</p>
            </div>

        </div>

</template>
```

**Script**

```
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                usuarios:[],
                busqueda: '',
                nombre: '',

            }
        },

        methods: {
            buscarUsuario() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:50995/api/GetUsuario?id=' + this.busqueda)
                    .then(response => {
                            this.usuarios = response.data,
                            this.nombre = response.data.Nombre

                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })
            },

            getUsuarios() {
                axios.get("http://localhost:50995/api/GetUsuarios")
                    .then(response => {
                        this.usuarios = response.data

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })

            }
        },

        created() {
                this.getUsuarios(),
                this.buscarUsuario()
        }


    }

</script>
```

As you can see, the `<p>{{nombre}}</p>` is populated with the data of the ID that i put in the input. But the table only shows blank data.

The `<p>{{nombre}}</p>` is only for test if the buscarUsuario() method works, and it's works but not with the table.

And, how can i reload the data of the table with the properties of the ID when i push the "Buscar" button?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong in your `buscarUsuario()` logic: you are overwriting the initial correct array of `usuario` objects with a single object of one `usuario`

```
axios.get('http://localhost:50995/api/GetUsuario?id=' + this.busqueda)
                    .then(response => {
/* REMOVE THIS LINE */      this.usuarios = response.data,
                            this.nombre = response.data.Nombre
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                    })
```

Comment: Hi, yes, but if i only do that, only <p>{{nombre}}</p> show the data.Nombre. But i want reload the data in the table with only one result of my query if i push the button "Buscar".

Comment: then use this (notice the square brackets) `this.usuarios = [response.data];`